# vb.net listview different display on design time and run time

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, runtime, design-time

for some reason/s, horizontal scrollbar appears on design time but not on runtime...I wonder why?

[image: designed time]
[image: run time]

Comment: look at the windows control bar also..

Comment: As far as I know, it just happens that it looks different at the two stages. I'd like to know why as well if somebody knows?

Comment: I hope someone will provide some information why... :(

Comment: it is because the LV is empty.  There is nothing to scroll at runtime.

Comment: I can view the scrollbar when I resize a column in the form..